# Unexpected T_FUNCTION

Tags: php, function, syntax-error

This is my function php for a login page and i keep getting T_function, i searched on the internet to try and figure it out but to no avail. any help thanks!.

```
<? php


Function redirect($page=) {

                header('location: ' . $page); 
                exit();
                }

//check login status

Function Check_login_status() {

            //IF $_SESSION ['Logged_in'] is set, return the status

            if (isset($_SESSION['Logged_in'])) {

                        Return $_SESSION['logged_in'];


                }       

                Return false;       
        }
?>
```

Comment: Please do not capitalize PHP keywords

Comment: Function redirect($page=) <-- you have an assignment operator without a value after, try resolving that first.

Comment: Sidenote: Don't forget to include [`session_start();`](http://www.php.net/session_start) ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a space in your opening PHP tag:

```
<? php
```

Should be

```
<?php
```

**and**

You have an unassigned value for your function parameter

```
Function redirect($page=) {
```

Should be

```
Function redirect($page) { // or you could put a default value as well
```